# adwaita header bar problem

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I'm having problem with adwaita title bar theme in nautilus.
What is the solution?

[image]

The one on the right is root nautilus.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and installed Unity desktop by

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Comment: How did you launch these two different-looking Nautilus windows? What is your Ubuntu version? You added the [18.04] tag, but it looks like Unity instead of GNOME. If the tag is correct, how did you install Unity? Is this a fresh installation or updated from an older Ubuntu version?

Comment: @pomsky it's possible to install Unity in 18.04.

Comment: @RolandiXor Yes, I wanted to check whether OP consciously installed Unity or it's a residue of an older release. Looks like OP somehow mixed two versions of Nautilus.

Comment: I wonder if one is the flatpack version? The one on the right has fewer bookmarks, so it is probably sandboxed.

Comment: right is root nautilus and version is 18.04 but i install unity desktop  by "sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop"

Comment: @MoutazBakier Thanks for providing more info. But please don't use comments for key details as comments may get deleted easily for various reasons. Instead always [edit] your question and add them, I did it for you this time :)

Comment: To acquire the traditional headerbar, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP should be set to Unity. Presumably, the way you started nautilus as root (you did not yet indicate, see pomsky's first question), the variable may not be set appropriately for your root instance. Anyway, launching a gui program as root is not anymore supported and being fased out.